# Can Google Places API be used without enabling billing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-development

I am using Google Places API in my android app to retrieve locations of nearby places such as schools or hospital & display their locations on the map.Now 3 weeks ago I enabled the api & integrated it with my app WITHOUT ENABLING BILLING and all requests were accepted & the api returned the locations.But when I used the app yesterday the api didn't return the locations & instead returned the message saying that request was denied & I had to enable billing in my Google account.

Now my query is why was I able to use that api without enabling billing for 20 days while I am unable to do it now.Is there a certain period till which requests are accepted without billing?I also tried regenerating the key & disabling & re-enabling the api but nothing worked.I can't use a credit card to enable billing since I don't have one.Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Google Places API requires billing to work.

It uses Pay-As-You-Go Pricing

[Check this for more Information](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing)

Answer (score 0):

Google Place APIs require billing. When you use these APIs it gives you some limited requested free then you have to enable billing. That's, why it worked for some days and after the limit ends,  it is saying to enable billing.